# MVC3 FileUpload (web helper) always null in Edit method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, properties, entity-framework-4.1, crud

I have a `FileUpload` (from microsoft.web.helpers) that is always null in the `Edit` `ActionResult` method. In the `Create` method, it works fine. Only difference is that its a different model in Edit, where I access the original properties through that. (if that makes sense). Here the code so you can see. First the models and then the controllers:

```
    public class Files
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> FileName { get; set; }

    public Artikel Artikel { get; set; }
}

public class Artikel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public bool Proof { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> FileUpload { get; set; }
    public string TextShort { get { return Text.Substring(0, 50); } }
}
```

HttpPost create:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Artikel artikel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                artikel.Date = DateTime.Now;
                db.Artikler.Add(artikel);
                db.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var file in artikel.FileUpload)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var folder = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/Artikler/" + artikel.Id.ToString());
                        if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
                        }

                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var path = Path.Combine(folder, fileName);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //ex something someting..
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(artikel);
    }
```

Edit:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var model = new Files
        {
            Artikel = db.Artikler.Find(id),
            FileName = db.GetPictures(id, Server.MapPath("~/uploads/Artikler/"))

        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

HttpPost edit:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Files files)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(files.Artikel).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                if (files.Artikel.FileUpload != null)
                {
                    foreach (var file in files.Artikel.FileUpload)
                    {
                        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            var folder = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/artikler/" + files.Artikel.Id.ToString());
                            if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
                            }

                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var path = Path.Combine(folder, fileName);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                    }
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(files);
    }
```

The markup:

```
@FileUpload.GetHtml()
```

So, clearly ive misunderstood something, or done something wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem comes from the `name` attribute of the `<input type="file">` element on the form.

For example in the Create action it looks like this (I suppose because it works):

```
<input type="file" name="FileUpload" />
```

and then it is automatically bound to the `FileUpload` property of the `Artikel` class which is what your Create action takes as argument.

In the Edit action I don't know how it is named. But I suppose the same. But because your Edit action takes `Files` as argument it must be named like this:

```
<input type="file" name="Artikel.FileUpload" />
```

so that it is bound to the `FileUpload` property of the `Artikel` property of your `Files` model. Also you should make sure that the form containing this file input has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.

So fix your markup in the view.

Comment: Im reopening the question Darin. The attribute didnt help. The markup is correct.

Comment: @Kasper Skov, then it's the input name.

Comment: Ah yeah shit!Its a helper called @FileUpload. It generates a name called FileUpload by it self. So cant really do anything about it. Ill look into redesigning the models tomorrow. Ill be in touch :)

Comment: I just added 'public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> FileUpload { get; set; }' to Files class. Solved the issue. Dont think theres a way to manipulate what input name the Html fileuploader helper makes.